# How do I get Shutter to open the GUI after taking a screenshot

Tags: shortcut-keys, shutter

I configured Ubuntu 14.10 to run `shutter -f` when I press Print Screen. But that just saves a file. How do I get the hotkey to not just run Shutter, but also place the screenshot in the clipboard and open the Shutter GUI  (to allow cropping etc)?

Answer (score 1):

I just tries it.  Go to Edit --> Preferences, and make sure that you have "Present main window after taking a screenshot" checked.  See image below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's the setting.  On my machine, however, after I take that screenshot, the Shutter GUI opens up blank and grey -- no image, no controls, nothing  but the app's chrome (borders).

Comment: What shutter version are you running?  I'm running Shutter 0.90.1, Rev.1259

Comment: It's Shutter v 0.92 Rev.1269